# Caffe net.forward call for multiple batches

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, pycaffe

I am using **ImageData** type of data in .prototxt file and trying to get the features from python code using `net.forward()` and `net.blobs` of **caffe** library. However, I get only 50 features after net.forward() call which is the **batch_size** which I have set in .prototxt file.

How can I get the features for subsequent batches? Do I have to call `net.forward()` multiple times?

Comment: yes. `forward()` performs **single** forward pass = 1 batch

Comment: Thanks! So do I have to call forward() in the loop? How can I give end conditions for the loop? Or is there any end of data kind of condition or it will be manual (as I know the number of input images)?

Comment: it's up to you - you know how much data you have.

Comment: Got it! Net.forward() returns dictionary of features data as output which I can check for emptiness as end condition of loop.